# Less not compiling parametric mixins

Tags: css, less

I am fairly new to Less and I was just running through some of the simple concepts and found that when ever I use a parametric mixin, it doesn't compile to the CSS file.

Example, this is my style.less file:

```
@color: #000;

.boxshadow (@shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4)) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
    -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
    box-shadow: @shadow;
}

.box{
    .boxshadow;
    color: @color;
}
```

and this my compiled style.css file:

```
.box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #000;
}
```

It's recognising the values on .boxshadow and carrying them through to .box, but it isn't compiling .boxshadow as it's own CSS class.

I have compiled with the command line and a Sublime Text 3 package, both outputting the same css.

Am I missing something simple?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code compiles as expected, what css you want?

Comment: The properties specified under `.boxshadow` mixin are getting applied to `.box` class only because ***`.boxshadow` was compiled***. It just doesn't get listed in your output CSS file because, well, it (parametric mixins) is not valid CSS. Parametric mixins are purely pre-processor stuff which helps you avoid repetition etc.

Comment: I was expecting the `@shadow` value to carry through within the `.boxshadow` styles and output that as it's own class `.boxshadow{-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);` etc.
I understand now that parametric mixins are just pre-processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want to create a mixin but you do not want that mixin to be output, you can put parentheses after it.

See [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin)

Comment: I see, this wasn't explained on the page I was following. Thanks!

Comment: I don't undertand, all the parametric mixins have parentheses and the output in the question of the OP already doing that